# Translate a regular expression

Tags: grep, regular-expression, mingw

I have .NET regular expression `<asp:textbox\b((?!maxlength).)*>` that matches text "<asp:textbox" not followed by "maxlength". I want to port this regular expression to MINGW. I'm fine with `grep` or whatever tool.

I managed to figure out `\<asp:TextBox\\b`. The one slash before < and two slashes before b already confused me, and I have no luck putting `((?!maxlength).)*>` back.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: for lookarounds, you need `grep -P` if it is supported in your setup... would suggest that you post sample text input and show which lines you need and which lines shouldn't be part of output... also, you should quote your regex inside single quotes to avoid shell interpretations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you need to add `-P` option of `grep` if you have it.

```
grep -P '\<asp:textbox\\b\((?!maxlength).*\>'
```

Also here not necessary you use [negative-look-ahead assertion](https://caspar.bgsu.edu/~courses/Stats/Labs/Handouts/grepadvanced.htm), and if your `grep` doesn't have/support `-P` option, use `grep` with reverse switch `grep -v`.

```
grep -v '\<asp:textbox\\b(maxlength.*\>'
```

Comment: to OP: also not sure if `\b` is actual characters in your input or it's word boundaries `\bword\b`! I assumed it's actual `\b`

Comment: I want \b for word boundary.

Comment: do `\bword\b` or `\<word\>` or use `-w` option of `grep` then.